# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) for my sql

Tags: sqlexception

I tried to importing an existing project which consists of Spring mvc & Hibernate while running application through TOMCAT
I'm having troubles with my project , it involves Hibernateand Mysql connection .

When I do the following :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:925)
    at ..
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a privelege issue. Try to run this on your console

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply I'll try to fire this query let me try

Comment: I did but I am getting same exception

Comment: @maheshchinta:- Did you try to restart your MySql server after exectuing the above query?

Comment: after restarting I am getting this error Your connection attempt failed for user root from your host to server at localhost:3306

Comment: @maheshchinta: Try opening services.msc from the start menu search box and try manually starting the MySQL service.